Проблема с pywatchman
столкнулся с проблемой Не удается разрешить импорт "pywatchman" в Django при создании лендинг сайта. Вот вся чать кода
try:
import pywatchman
except ImportError:
pywatchman = None
пробовал устанавливать pywatchman и вылезала вот такая ошибка-
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pywatchman
Failed to build pywatchman
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pywatchman, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
